# TextView too big for Screen

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that contains 32 lines of text.  On rotation to landscape the TextView becomes too large for the screen and therefore I would like it to split into 2, 16 line TextViews but do not know if this is possible.  This is what I have so far.

I know I could do a test to see if getHeight() > screen height but even if it is, I wouldn't know what to do.

```
        TextView displayMethod = new TextView(getActivity());
        displayMethod.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        displayMethod.setClickable(false);
        displayMethod.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        displayMethod.setTextSize(14);
        displayMethod.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);  

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10,20,10, 0);
        displayMethod.setLayoutParams(params);

        int i = 0;      
        while (i < 32){

            String x = method.getNextLine();

            displayMethod.append(x + "\n");             
            i++;
        }
        linLayout.addView(displayMethod);
```

Comment: So are you saying when you rotate to landscape you want to have two TextViews side-by-side? (Like in a newspaper where a story is split into multiple columns)

Comment: you can achieve this by defining another xml layout file with 2 columns into the folder "layout-land"

Comment: @TylerAndFriends Yes, spot on! It needs to be programatically generated though, not all done in the XML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a behavior of splitting the `TextView` in two pieces when viewed in landscape would be a great way to use all of your screen real-estate, and is actually very simple.

Next to your `res/layout` folder, create a new layout folder named `layout-land`, and in here put your new layout containing two different `TextView` objects. Note that the name of the new layout file in `layout-land` needs to be exactly the same as your original layout from the `layout` folder. (Copy-paste actually suggested here).

From here, you have two options:

-- Update your original layout in your `layout` folder to have two `TextView` objects stacked vertically. Make sure that the ids of your `TextViews` are the same in this layout compared to your landscape layout in `layout-land`. No code changes are required in this option.

-- Leave your original layout as is, but check for the existance of the landscape-specific `TextView` in your `Activity` and fill either one or two `TextViews` appropriately. For example...

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
TextView textViewLandscapeOnly = findViewById(R.id.textViewLandscapeOnly);

if(textViewLandscapeOnly == null) {
    //We're in portrait mode, so only fill the first text view with all 32 lines.
} else {
    //We're in landscape mode, so fill both text views, each with 16 lines.
}
```

Comment: Problem, I have to generate the TextViews programatically for reasons I need not explain.  Your approach would work, but can it be done programatically similar to my code snippet